# How to create a command and a command handler in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I am new to Laravel.

I am trying to create a command and a command handler in a project of mine. What is the correct way to do it from the command line.

I tried to use the following

```
php artisan make:command WhenFormSubmited
```

But that seems to create a `self handling` command.

I want to put the handler some where else so the handlers are in a separate folder.

Can I just manually create a handler? Is there a naming convention that I have to stick with for it to work? How would the command know the location of the corresponding controller?

Is there a way to specify an non-selfhandling command from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command :

```
php artisan make:command MyCommand --handler
```

`--handler` Indicates that handler class should be generated.